# How to set different fonts for input placeholder and value?

Tags: html, css, placeholder, html-input

Is the any way to set different fonts for an input placeholder and value? I need to set diffrent fonts for my input placeholder and value because they use diffrent languages. The placeholder uses an right tonleft language but the vakue uses english. Is it possible in CSS3?

Comment: @j08691 I think there is a diferrence between font and color! But thanks it was useful

Comment: It shows you how to style the placeholder attribute via CSS. What's the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by targeting the placeholder text in css. Then setting `color` on the input to be something else

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}

:-moz-placeholder { 
   color: red;  
}

::-moz-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: red;  
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aTJhu/)